# Prove that if the initial value of $\dot{x} = X(x)$ belongs to $Z$ and the vector field is tangent to curve Z, then the solution also belongs to $Z$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-dynamics

Let $Z = \{x\in \mathbb{R}^{2}: F(x) = 0\}$ be a simple disjoint closed curve, and the vector field $X$ is perpendicular to the gradient of $F$ on $Z$.  Prove that if the initial value of $\dot{x} = X(x)$  belongs to $Z$, then the solution also belongs to $Z$.

We can get that the vector field is tangent to curve Z. So, in pictures, it's like true by using the existence and uniqueness theorem. How to do complete proof?

Comment: Not sure what a simple disjoint curve is. Parametrize $Z$ by a curve $\gamma(t)\,.$ It satisfies  $\dot\gamma=X(\gamma)$ because $X$ is tangent. Then, as you say, existence and uniqueness theorem aka Picard Lindelöf.

Comment: $X$ needs to be Lipschitz, else all standard examples of non-uniqueness apply. You might get a weaker statement if $X$ is orthogonal to $\nabla F$ everywhere, also outside $Z$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\alpha(t)$ be a solution with initial value in $Z$, that is, $F(\alpha(0))=0$. Then
$$
\frac{d}{dt}F(\alpha(t)) = \langle \text{grad} F(\alpha(t)),\alpha(t)' \rangle = \langle \text{grad} F(\alpha(t)),X(\alpha(t)) \rangle = 0
$$
therefore, $t \mapsto F(\alpha(t))$ is constant and we must have $F(\alpha(t)) = 0$ for all $t$, that is, $\alpha(t) \in Z$ for all $t$.